# Импорт координат из Photoshop для clip-path

Tags: css, photoshop

Возник вопрос, при работе с этим инструментом можно ли как нибудь автоматизировать процесс поиска "координат". Потому как фигуру нужную нарисовать пером в фотошопе я могу за пару минут, а вот конвертировать этот рисунок в координаты уйдет 2 часа. (обшая высота / на текущую высоту точки для Y для X аналогично).
Есть ли способ импортировать координаты из любого графического редактора????

Пример

```
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 73.566%, 99.2926% 74.3142%, 97.42765% 76.4754%, 95.81993% 77.97174%, 90.99678% 82.29426%, 87.71704% 84.87116%, 82.76527% 88.2793%, 78.19936% 90.93932%, 74.14791% 92.93433%, 71.1254% 94.18121%, 66.23794% 95.7606%, 61.41479% 96.92436%, 56.91318% 97.67249%, 53.37621% 98.00499%, 50.16077% 98.12968%, 46.94534% 98.08811%, 43.15113% 97.79717%, 39.16399% 97.17373%, 36.01286% 96.59185%, 32.15434% 95.51122%, 28.29582% 94.18121%, 25.08039% 92.93433%, 22.2508% 91.60432%, 18.39228% 89.35993%, 14.791% 87.2818%, 10.99678% 84.53865%, 7.3955% 81.62926%, 4.50161% 78.96924%, 1.99357% 76.433;
background-color: #000;
```

Comment: приведите пример кода clip-path

Comment: Нарисовать и сохранить как svg (начиная с версии CC 2017)?